# extracting information from prop file

Tags: java, android, properties, extract

I got a prop file that I want to extract from it the version release number (as a String).
The file looks like this :

```
ro.build.version.sdk=19

ro.build.version.codename=REL

ro.build.version.release=4.4.2

ro.build.date=Mon Oct 27 00:53:09 IST 2014

ro.build.date.utc=1414363989
```

I don't know the version release number, allIi know that I got this prop on my file.
How can I get with Java the value of this prop, and to save it on a String variable?
(Here it will be 4.4.2)

Comment: Did you bother to do an Internet search first? You would have found something like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: @MarsAtomic I see nothing tagged as android here.

Comment: @AaronC The properties themselves suggest Android. Android SDK 19 = Android v 4.4 KitKat, but let's retag for the sake of propriety.

Comment: @MarsAtomic true. I didn't take notice to the values.

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file like you normally would and store each line in an arraylist.

```
ArrayList<String> lines; //store the lines here
String releaseNum = "";
```

Then loop through:

```
    for(String s : lines){
        keyVal = s.split("="); // keyVal is now an array of len 2, keyVal[0] being the key, keyVal[1] being the value.
        if(keyVal[0].equals("ro.build.version.release")){
            releaseNum = keyVal[1]; //got the value
        }
    }
```

Now releaseNum is the value you wanted to retrieve.

If this is android however, use the `Properties` class.
Example:

```
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "fileName.properties";

        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        prop.load(inputStream);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
        String releaseNum = prop.getProperty("ro.build.version.release");
```

Comment: You might as well provide the Android specific code as well -- you can adapt your code easily using the link I provided below the OP. The expanded information may help someone else running into this answer.